# Best way of dealing with shared state in a real time system in dotnet core background service

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core, backgroundworker

I have a background service `IHostedService` in dotnet core 3.1 that takes requests from 100s of clients(machines in a factory) using sockets (home rolled). My issue is that multiple calls can come in on different threads to the same method on a class which has access to an object (shared state). This is common in the codebase. The requests also have to be processed in the correct order.

The reason that this is not in a database is due to performance reasons (real time system). I know I can use a lock, but I don't want to have locks all over the code base.

What is a standard way to handle this situation. Do you use an in-memory database? In-memory cache? Or do I just have to add locks everywhere?

```
public class Machine
{
    
    public MachineState {get; set;}

    // Gets called by multiple threads from multiple clients 
    public bool CheckMachineStatus()
    {
        return MachineState.IsRunning;
    }

    // Gets called by multiple threads from multiple clients 
    public void SetMachineStatus()
    {
        MachineState = Stopped;
    }
}
```

**Update**

Here's an example. I have a console app that talks to a machine via sockets, for weighing products. When the console app initializes it will load data into memory (information about the products being weighed). All of this is done on the main thread, to keep data integrity.

When a call comes in from the weigh-er on Thread 1, it will get switched to the main thread to access the product information, and to finish any other work like raising events for other parts of the system.

Currently this switching from Thread 1,2, ...N to the main thread is done by a home rolled solution, and was done to avoid having locking code all over the code base. This was written in .Net 1.1 and since moving to dotnet core 3.1. I thought there might be a framework, library, tool, technique etc that might handle this for us, or just a better way.

This is an existing system that I'm still learning. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: What kind of data are you saving? Is it relational? Can you put it in a key/value store? You'd get a better response if you provide more context.

Comment: Performance and atomic consistency are usually a trade-off between one or the other. If you don't want to use a lock, you can look at the `System.Threading.Interlocked` class for some operations which can be done atomically. If all you're doing is reading/updating a boolean variable from multiple threads, the Interlocked class will let you do that without needing to lock. If your use case is more complicated than that, you need to describe it otherwise we can't be much help

Comment: @insane_developer The data can be anything, an object, list of objects, a number of variables. I'm aware I can use something like EF core in-memory provider, Ravendb or Litedb amongst others.  As I am new to this domain(coming from a web background) I thought there would be a standard way of dealing with this scenario. I understand it's a bit of generic question and will try and update my example. Thanks.

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson Yeah, we have code that handles atomic consistency like you mentioned Lock, Interlocked and ManualResetEvent. I was looking to see if there was a better way. Thanks.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your problem, but if you have to handle multiple threaded requests, in chronological order, wouldn't a "Multiple-Producer, Single Consumer" pattern simplify things greatly?  Have your socket handlers dump "commands" at the end of a single, thread-safe collection, then exit.  Another thread acts as the processor, taking items from the head of the collection sequentially and executing them one at a time in the order they were received.

Comment: Your biggest problem is going to be synchronising the 100s of machines on the network to know when data was actually recorded - which is different from when it was sent and different from when it was received. Process systems in factories are very fragile to this kind of inconsistency.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I think I'll go for something like that. I just need a way of storing the data now as it'll still be accessed by multi threads. Looking into in-memory key/value stores.

Answer (score 4):

Using an in-memory database is an option, as long as you are willing to delegate all concurrency-inducing situations to the database, and do nothing using code. For example if you must update a value in the database depending on some condition, then the condition should be checked by the database, not by your own code.

Adding locks everywhere is also an option, that will almost certainly lead to unmaintainable code quite quickly. The code will probably be riddled with hidden bugs from the get-go, bugs that you will discover one by one over time, usually under the most unfortunate circumstances.

You must realize that you are dealing with a difficult problem, with no magic solutions available. Managing shared state in a multithreaded application has always been a source of pain.

My suggestion is to encapsulate all this complexity inside thread-safe classes, that the rest of your application can safely invoke. How you make these classes thread-safe depends on the situation.

1. Using locks is the most flexible option, but not always the most efficient because it has the potential of creating contention.
2. Using thread-safe collections, like the [`ConcurrentDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2) for example, is less flexible because the thread-safety guarantees they offer are limited to the integrity of their internal state. If for example you must update one collection based on a condition obtained from another collection, then the whole operation can not be made atomic by just using thread-safety collections. On the other hand these collections offer better performance than the simple locks.
3. Using [immutable collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/march/net-framework-immutable-collections), like the [`ImmutableQueue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablequeue-1) for example, is another interesting option. They are less efficient both memory and CPU wise than the concurrent collections (adding/removing is in many cases O(Log n) instead of O(1)), and not more flexible than them, but they are very efficient specifically at providing snapshots of actively processed data. For updating atomically an immutable collection, there is the handy [`ImmutableInterlocked.Update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutableinterlocked.update) method available. It updates a reference of an immutable collection with an updated version of the same collection, without using locks. In case of contention with other threads it may invoke the supplied transformation multiple times, until it wins the race.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I wanted to off load all concurrency situations to the database. I thought there might be a common framework/tool or database used in this scenario. Something like Redis, Dotnet Core MemoryCache, or other in-memory stores.

Comment: @ctb the `MemoryCache` is just a cache. It offers expiration policies and such, and thread-safety for updating single keys, but does not offer atomicity by itself when you want to update a key based on the value of another key. So if you want to do anything non-trivial, you'll need extra synchronization (locks). About Redis I can't comment because I don't know much about it. When talking about in-memory databases I had in mind the SQL Server In-memory OLTP, that can run stored procedures, so it should be able to handle concurrency well.

Comment: You can also look at Channels<T> Or TPL DataFlow for in-memory pipeline/queue ( or pub-sub) behaviour. These are high performing data structures and are completely thread-safe and built for async programming. You could also look at Reactive Extensions Rx.

Comment: I decided on channels so we can have many producers and a single consumer. Seems the best way to handle this is to consume on a single thread. I might have a use for Rx later, but would like to avoid that complexity if possible.